# A relation among projections of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

This is a follow-up question on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229185/collection-of-projection-operators-in-finite-dimension-and-algebraic-techinques/229295#229295). Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra and $P$ be its projection lattice.

For $p,s,q \in P$, let us define $ p \perp q \mid s \iff ps^\perp q = 0$ where $s^\perp = 1-s$.

Let $P_0 \subset P$ be a complete sublattice of $P$. Is the following true over $P_0$ (i.e., for any $p,q,r,s \in P_0$):
\begin{align*}
  r \perp p \mid (q \vee s), \quad r \perp q \mid (p \vee s) \implies r \perp (p\vee q) \mid s\;?
\end{align*}

Comment: What conditions are you having in mind? You must formulate your question more clearly, because, being a mathematician, I would say the conditions are precisely those that you gave.

Comment: @Anton, not sure what you mean. Let me ask this: Is the statement true for every complete sublattice $P_0$, or one needs to assume something more about $P_0$?

Comment: @Anton, OK, I understand what you mean. I just reworded it as a yes/no question. But my guess is the answer is no. I was hoping that there is a simpler condition that one can verify for $P_0$, from which mine follows, but perhaps not. In other words, I was hoping that someone recognize a connection with some other more well-understood condition. Otherwise, I will delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is false - let $r=1$ and take any distinct rank $1$ projections $p,q,s\in M_2$ so $p\vee q=p\vee s=q\vee s=1$.

Comment: Or just $p = q = r = 1$ and $s = 0$.

Comment: @Tristan, how can $r=1$ and a rank 1 projection at the same time?

Comment: Yep, that'll do it!

Comment: Oops, I meant $s$ for the second $r$. In any case, Nik's answer is even simpler.

Comment: @Nik and Tristan, OK... fair enough. Maybe I should have mentioned distinct elements $p,q,r,s$, but Tristan's example seem to cover that. Though not sure if I understand that example correctly. Isn't $M_2$ 4-dimensional? Then, why $p \vee q = 1$ for example?

Comment: $M_2$ is 4-dimensional but it's elements are operators on a 2-dimensional Hilbert space, so $1$ is the unique rank 2 projection.

Comment: Ah... OK, thanks. My confusion again between operators and the underlying Hilbert space. (Mistake: thinking about operators on $M_2$...)